# Wordpress theme angularJS promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress

I have a wordpress angularjs theme but it's not loading content using promises. I'm trying to do a few HTTP requests but I can't figure out an easy way of achieving it.

I have looked at tutorials on promises and factories but anything I try results in an error. Can anybody show an example of something that would work?

Here's each of the requests:

```
$http.get('wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?filter[name]=' + $routeParams.slug)
$http.get('wp-json/theme/v1/post/' + $scope.post.id)
$http.get('wp-json/wp/v2/media/' + $scope.post.featured_image)
```

Here's my controller. Once I can see how it will work with promises I will be able to figure it out easier. The second and third HTTP request above are called on callback on the first request.

```
app.controller('Post', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', 'service', function($scope, $routeParams, $http, WPService) {    
    // requests
}]);
```

Comment: what you want to achieve? are you just trying to ask to call the `2nd`, `3rd` `get` requests on the success of `1st` ?

Comment: Yea it's only a simple request, i'm just trying to use promises so the page loads properly

Comment: just chain them (all `get` requests) one by one in the `success` callback

Answer (score 0):

```
$http.get(first_url).success(function (firstResult) {
   $http.get(second_url).success(function (secondResult) { 
      $http.get(third_url).success(function (thirdResult){
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: The last http request is a  large image so it then takes some time after the page has loaded to load the image

Comment: that's not a problem, before firing the `3rd` request; in `success` of `2nd` request show a loading `gif` and in `success` of `3rd` request hide the `gif`. That'll help you mimic the background work.